# HTML - refresh page to https version of same page on IIS server

Tags: html, iis

We have forms on our web page that we need to encrypt. The SSL already works so we just need to redirect users going to the forms pages to the have link read:

https://ourdomain.com/contact-us.aspx instead of http://ourdomain.com/contact-us.aspx.

I added the following line to the header but the page naturally keeps refreshing itself:

```
     <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=https://ourdomain.com/contact-us.aspx"/>
```

Of course, I told the page on reload to refresh itself so it keeps doing it. What is the best way to redirect the page so that it loads as an https page just once?

This is not an Apache server so adding an .htaccess file is not an option (regrettably!).
The links to the contact pages (there are 4 of them) can be easily set to https instead of http, but since some users might have the contact forms bookmarked I'd like to redirect those users to the encrypted pages.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to do it via your IIS configuration. I think the meta-Tag will not help you because you can not check wether the user is connected via https or http.

My *JavaScript solution* would be:

```
if(location.protocol.indexOf("https") === -1) {
    location.href = location.href.replace("http", "https");
}
```

An [IIS solution can be found here](http://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html).

Comment: Thank you. I don't have administrative rights over the server, I'll have to ask our DC for that. I'll try the Javascript solution as well.